# Yammer 3rd party application access

Tags: yammer

Is there a way to limit the 3rd party applications that can authenticate to a Yammer network? Currently it looks like there are only 2 options, either we restrict any 3rd party applications from authenticating, or we can allow all. Would it be possible for a verified admin to create the application with their own account, and would this not count as a 3rd party application, but rather an internal application?

Thanks!

Comment: Any help from Microsoft or Yammer would be greatly appreciated, as there is no direct technical support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling 3rd party applications is an "all or nothing" setting. Once this setting is made, all 3rd party applications will be disabled and tokens will no longer be valid between 3rd party apps and Yammer. An alternative in this situation would be for admins to manually send the Data Export to the 3rd party app instead.